# Какой стек технологий нужно знать для создания своего сервера из ПК?

Tags: сервер, веб-сервер

У меня есть ПК, не самый мощный, средний офисный. Хочу, сделать из него веб сервер. Мне не нужно миллионы запросов, а просто чтобы мини веб приложение работало.

Какие технологии и практики нужно освоить, чтобы сделать такое?

Comment: посмотрите nginx и Apache. В локальной сети очень просто заведётся, а вот если захотите, чтобы сайт был доступен в сети интернет, то нужно у провайдера купить внешний IP